# How can I override HashMap's putAll to call put on each <K,V> pair?

Tags: java, hashmap, overriding, key-value

I am trying to override PutAll in order to loop through the  pairs and call put on them, since I am using a custom [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) object. I have tried this:

```
        @Override
        public void putAll(final Map m) {
            Iterator iterator = m.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
                put(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue());
            }
        }
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Compiling the source code....
$javac HelloWorld.java 2>&1
HelloWorld.java:109: error: no suitable method found for put(Object,Object)
                put(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue());
                ^
    method UniqueHashMap.put(K,V) is not applicable
      (actual argument Object cannot be converted to K by method invocation conversion)
    method HashMap.put(K,V) is not applicable
      (actual argument Object cannot be converted to K by method invocation conversion)
    method AbstractMap.put(K,V) is not applicable
      (actual argument Object cannot be converted to K by method invocation conversion)
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in class UniqueHashMap
    V extends Object declared in class UniqueHashMap
1 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), you seem to have generics K,V use them like this,

```
@Override
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
  Iterator<? extends K> iterator = m.keySet().iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    K key = iterator.next();
    put(key, m.get(key));
  }
}
```

Comment: Not using bounded type parameters will prevent you from calling, eg `HashMap<String,Base>.putAll(HashMap<String,Derived>)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess your custom map class has type parameters, so your correct override should be:

```
@Override
void putAll(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m) {
  Iterator<Map.Entry<? extends K,? extends V>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<? extends K,? extends V> pairs = iterator.next();
    put(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue());
  }
}
```

where `K` and `V` are the type variables used for your class.

Comment: HelloWorld.java:105: error: putAll(Map<? extends K#1,? extends V#1>) in UniqueHashMap cannot implement putAll(Map<? extends K#2,? extends V#2>) in Map
void putAll(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m) {
     ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
  where K#1,V#1,K#2,V#2 are type-variables:
    K#1 extends Object declared in class UniqueHashMap
    V#1 extends Object declared in class UniqueHashMap
    K#2 extends Object declared in interface Map
    V#2 extends Object declared in interface Map

Comment: HelloWorld.java:106: error: incompatible types
  Iterator<Map.Entry<? extends K,? extends V>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator();
                                                                               ^
  required: Iterator<Entry<? extends K,? extends V>>
  found:    Iterator<Entry<CAP#1,CAP#2>>
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in class UniqueHashMap
    V extends Object declared in class UniqueHashMap
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends K from capture of ? extends K
    CAP#2 extends V from capture of ? extends V

Comment: @Alexandru because your `UniqueHashMap` has even more raw-types. Post the rest of your code.

Comment: I tried making it public, and then using Iterator<Entry<? extends K,? extends V>> for my iterator declaration but then I get this: HelloWorld.java:106: error: Entry is not public in HashMap; cannot be accessed from outside package
  Iterator<Entry<? extends K,? extends V>> iterator = m.entrySet().iterator();
           ^
1 error